# Send a message to a YouTube Channel via API

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-plus

I am retrieving a YouTube Channel ID via YouTube API, but I'd like to contact (send a message) this channel in some way. I notice that some YouTube channels have a "Send message" button in "About" tab, but some doesn't, and in the YouTube API v3 there is nothing related to it.

Another possibility that I thought was retrieve the Google+ ID associated with the YouTube channel, but again the API doesn't provide a way to send a message.

The last alternative is to get the Google account's email, but I think that is not possible due to privacy rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, YouTube's [Messages and video sharing API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_messages) has been [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/deprecated) without a replacement interface in the v3 API.

Most YouTube channels are now linked with a Google Account.  A potential workaround would be to request information about a channel using the [`channels/list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) endpoint, seeing if a Google+ Account has been linked, and looking up the resulting user id with the Google+ API with the [`people/get`](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get) method.